# How do I learn how to design webpages?

Tags: learning

As a developer, I love writing code, and I like to think I'm fairly good at it.

However, my chosen field is Web Development, which almost always requires the developer to also act as designer.

I can tell if a design is good or not, I can offer suggestions to improve the layout or UX. But I cannot pick a color scheme, I cannot create a layout, and I am terrible at generating graphics.

As a developer, how can I pickup design?